# Flutter & Sqflite: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I'm currently trying to create a DB in my flutter app.

In a database.dart file I have:

```
void CreateBD() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   final database = openDatabase(
    //on choisi le path de la bd
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'hyrule_database.db'),
    //initialisation des tables
    onCreate: (db, version) {
      // Run the CREATE TABLE statement on the database.
      return db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE foods(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT,image TEXT, description TEXT, cookingEffect TEXT, category TEXT, commonLocations list<TEXT>, heartsRecovered INTEGER);'
            'CREATE TABLE nonfoods(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT,image TEXT, description TEXT,category TEXT, commonLocations list<TEXT>, drops list<TEXT>);'
            'CREATE TABLE equipments(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT,image TEXT, description TEXT, attack INTEGER, category TEXT, commonLocations list<TEXT>, defense INTEGER);'
            'CREATE TABLE materials(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT,image TEXT, description TEXT, cookingEffect TEXT, category TEXT, commonLocations list<TEXT>, heartsRecovered INTEGER);'
            'CREATE TABLE monsters(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT,image TEXT, description TEXT, category TEXT, commonLocations list<TEXT>, drops list<TEXT>);'
            'CREATE TABLE treasure(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT,image TEXT, description TEXT, category TEXT, commonLocations list<TEXT>, drops list<TEXT>)',
      );
    },
    //version afin de laisser la posibilité de upgrade et downgrade
    version: 1,
  );
}

Future<Database> connectBD()async{
  final database = openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'hyrule_database.db'),
  );
  return database;
}
```

And for every table i've create CRUD functions , here an exemple with food table:

```
  // Insertion
  Future<void> insertFood(Food food) async {
    final db = await connectBD();
    await db.insert(
      'foods',
      food.toMap(),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }
  //récupération
  Future<List<Food>> foods() async {
    final db = await connectBD();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('foods');
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Food(
        id: maps[i]['id'],
        name: maps[i]['name'],
        image: maps[i]['image'],
        heartsRecovered: maps[i]['hearts_recovered'],
        description: maps[i]['description'],
        cookingEffect: maps[i]['cooking_effect'],
        commonLocations: maps[i]['common_locations'],
        category: maps[i]['category'],
      );
    });
  }
  //update
  Future<void> updateFood(Food food) async {
    final db = await connectBD();
    await db.update(
      'foods',
      food.toMap(),
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [food.id],
    );
  }
  //delete
  Future<void> deleteFood(int id) async {
    final db = await connectBD();
    await db.delete(
      'foods',
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
  }
```

Then I try to execute the creation, and I only end up with the error :

***Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)***

the file I use to execute look like :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:projet_flutter/Utils/hyrule_bd.dart';
import 'package:projet_flutter/Utils/fill_bd.dart';
import 'package:projet_flutter/models/food_model.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';


class TestApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<TestApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CreateBD();
    //remplirBD();

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
        child:FutureBuilder<List<Food>>(
              future: foods(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text('${snapshot.data}');
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print("erreur test: ${snapshot.error}");
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
          }

          // By default, show a loading spinner.
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

My  pubspec.yaml :

```
name: projet_flutter
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: 0.13.4
  sqflite: any
  path: any

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

I'm currently learning Flutter dev, so i was wondering what went wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sqflite doesn't support web (https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite), which was what I was trying to build.

Comment: Oh okay. If you wanna try SQLite on web, you can check [drift](https://pub.dev/packages/drift) once. Happy coding!

Comment: Could be better if you mark it as correct answer to help others know it easier.

Comment: I have a to wait for 2 days before mark it corrct but i will ! I'm trying drift thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this happens after adding new dependencies into pubspec file.

Try running the following command from the project terminal:

```
flutter clean
```

And then re-run the project.

Comment: Hi ! i've tried to do that and also change sqflite version, but I don't have any changes , the error stays the same